# Remove multiple Items or rows from listbox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I want to delete Multiple rows of listbox, I tried this

```
For teller = 0 To 170 Step 1

        ListBox1.Items.Remove(teller)

    Next
```

But that doesn't work. How do I delete the first 170 rows in my listbox? :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that as you remove items, your list becomes shorter, so you will run out of items. So, just remove the first record on each pass:

**Updated to reflect minitech's comments**

```
For teller = 0 To 169
   ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0)
Next
```

Comment: That will remove the first 171 items, not the first 170. Also, minor thing, `Step 1` is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Since removing an item from a list shifts the rest of them up, simply remove the first item multiple times:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 170
    Me.ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0)
Next
```

You were also using `Remove` instead of `RemoveAt`, which removes an item by reference, not by index.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Dim count as Integer

count = ListBox1.Items.Count ''Or 170

For teller = 1 To count Step 1

        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0)

    Next
```

**EDIT**
As minitech stated it is always a good idea to remove the first item if you want to clear out a list or grid or any other collection of the first X items.